# Não consigo Ler o resultado do meu cookie no Navegador Chrome, o que Fazer?

Tags: javascript

Tenho seguinte código:

No arquivo `cookieSimplescont2.js`:

```js
function criarCookie(valorCookie){
 //Criar objeto data
 var data = new Date();

 // setando o tempo de vida do cookie
 data.setTime(data.getTime()+120000);

 //Criando a estrutura do Cookie
 document.cookie = "primeiroCookie="+valorCookie+" ; expires="+data.toUTCString()+" ; path=/";

 return "Sucesso";

}

function lendoCookie(){
    return document.cookie;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cookies</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cookieSimplescont2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HTML SO PARA TESTES--- Testando Cookies</h1>

 <button onclick="alert(criarCookie('DiaBonito'))">Criar Cookie</button>
 <button onclick="alert(lendoCookie())">Lendo Cookie</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Pois bem, para a função `LendoCookie()` funcionar antes tenho que clicar em *Criar Cookie* mas só porque eu definir um tempo de espiração do `cookie` curto de 2 minutos, a `funçãoLendoCookie()` retorna a chave do `cookie` quando abro o arquivo `cookieSimplescont2.html` usando o IE ou o Firefox, mas não no chrome. Já fui nas configurações de cookies do Chrome e no campo privacidade escolhi a opção "Permitir a configuração de dados locais (recomendado)." mas mesmo assim não retorna valor nenhum, alguém sabe me dizer o por que ?

Comment: Você está usando um servidor web? tipo wamp ou xampp?

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento não

Comment: @mandy então os cookies não funcionarão como expliquei aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182596/3635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `document.cookie` não funcionam no protocolo `file:///` e muitas vezes não funcionam se o dominio acessado for `http://localhost` e as vezes nem o `http://127.0.0.1` aceita a não ser que sejam setados via "header", o que geralmente só pode ser feito via back-end.

Para evitar isto você pode tentar instalar algo como Apache, Nginx, lightTTPD ou IIS ou até mesmo usar servidores locais para desenvolvimento (assim que puder eu coloco alguns exemplos).

Após instalar o servidor "http" em sua máquina basta acessar jogar o seu .html e .js na `htdocs` (geralmente apache) ou se já tiver um servidor http, então basta tentar os seguintes endereços:

1. `http://127.0.0.1`
2. Se o primeiro não funcionar tente o IP local da sua máquina, por exemplo algo semelhante a `http://192.168.1.55` ou semelhante ao `http://10.0.0.55`

Ainda sim usar IPs locais dinâmicos pode ser um baita problema, já que eles costumam mudar, então você pode criar um "pseudo host" na sua máquina, basta editar o arquivo `hosts` (se for Windows, logo edito com um exemplo Linux).

## Windows

1. Abra o `notepad.exe` (Bloco de notas) como administrador, clicando como o direito do mouse selecione executar como administrador
2. Desative o antivírus temporariamente
3. No `notepad.exe` clique em:

   - pt-BR: <kbd>Arquivo</kbd> > <kbd>Abrir...</kbd>
   - pt-PT: <kbd>Ficheiro</kbd> > <kbd>Abrir...</kbd>
   - en: <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Open...</kbd>
4. Irá aparecer a janela para navegar e escolher o arquivo, cole no campo este endereço: `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
5. Após a linha: `# localhost name resolution is handled within dns itself.` adicione isto:

   ```
   # localhost name resolution is handled within dns itself.
       127.0.0.1       localhost
       ::1             localhost
       127.0.0.1       meusite.local #adicione esta linha
   ```
6. Salve o documento e reative o antivírus
7. Reinicie o seu servidor HTTP (Apache, etc)
8. Digite na barra de endereço do teu navegador isto http://meusite.local/

## Mac OSX

1. Abra o Terminal
2. Digite (não sei ao certo qual é o correto):

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/hosts
   ```

   ou
      sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
3. Vá até a última linha pelo `nano` e adicione algo assim:

   ```
   127.0.0.1       meusite.local
   ```
4. Aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> para salvar (Não é <kbd>Cmd</kbd> é <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> mesmo)
5. Aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> para sair
6. Reinicie o servidor HTTP (Apache, etc)
7. Digite na barra de endereço do teu navegador isto http://meusite.local/

## Conclusão

Este Host será acessível somente na sua máquina local e lhe permitirá "simular" acesso ao `http://localhost` como se estivesse acessando um outro site qualquer através do pseudo-domínio `meusite.local`, assim evitará problemas ao setar o `document.cookie` no Chrome e no Safari

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que realmente pode ser alguma configuração local. Colocando o seu exemplo no jsFiddle ele funciona corretamente.

```js
function criarCookie(valorCookie) {
  //Criar objeto data
  var data = new Date();

  // setando o tempo de vida do cookie
  data.setTime(data.getTime() + 120000);

  //Criando a estrutura do Cookie
  document.cookie = "primeiroCookie=" + valorCookie + " ; expires=" + data.toUTCString() + " ; path=/";

  return "Sucesso";

}

function lendoCookie() {
  return document.cookie;
}
```

```html
<h1>HTML SO PARA TESTES--- Testando Cookies</h1>

<button onclick="alert(criarCookie('DiaBonito'))">Criar Cookie</button>
<button onclick="alert(lendoCookie())">Lendo Cookie</button>
```

Segue o link do [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2ndg8a4/1/).

Aqui comigo funcionou perfeitamente.