# Perdendo cookie (criado em javascript) ao trocar de página

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Na página HOME gravo um valo "x" em cookie.

```
var dataAtual = new Date();
var expire = new Date();
expire.setDate(dataAtual.getDate() + 1);

document.cookie = "NomeCookie=ValorCookie; expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
```

Quando acesso a página Cadastro (por exemplo).

```
var valor = document.cookie;
```

O valor retorna todos os outros cookies já existentes menos o que acabei de criar.
Como posso resolver isso? (se for possível).

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Possíveis causa do problema

- Localhost e Google Chrome / Safari

  Você está usando um navegador Safari ou Chrome com o dominio `http://localhost`, por algum motivo estes navegadores no dominio `localhost` não permitem que tecnologias front-end adicionem cookies, uma tentativa de solução é acessar via `http://127.0.0.1`, se o problema persistir você pode tentar criar um dominio "falso" editando o `hosts` (se estiver em windows) como expliquei nesta resposta:

  - [Não consigo Ler o resultado do meu cookie no Navegador Chrome, o que Fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182596/3635)
- Diferentes dominios/sub-dominios

  Se grava um cookie via javascript na página `http://foo.bar.com` e mudar para `http://bar.com` o cookie não poderá ter acesso
- Diferentes níveis de pasta

  Se grava o cookie diretamente ele vai gravar no nivel da pasta atual, suponde que crie um cookie na página `http://site/foo/bar/` ele só será acessivel as rotas que começarem com `foo/bar` como por exemplo:

  - `http://site/foo/bar/`
  - `http://site/foo/bar/baz`
  - `http://site/foo/bar/oi.html`

  Para que funcione em todos níveis basta mudar adicionar ao teu script o `path=/`, ele vai dizer que o cookie pode ser acessado deste o `root` (da url), ou seja em qualquer página dentro do mesmo domínio, o código deve ficar assim:

  ```
  var dataAtual = new Date();
  var expire = new Date();
  expire.setDate(dataAtual.getDate() + 1);

  document.cookie = "NomeCookie=ValorCookie; expires=" + expire.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
  ```

Comment: Era só adicionar o caminho da pasta, Obrigado.

Comment: Excelente como sempre.

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo funcional, verifique se consegue sanar seu problema seguindo o passo a passo. Não identifiquei erro no seu script.
[Exemplo funcional](https://jsfiddle.net/sxbynpw1/)